# CSS: Django button and search bar inline

Tags: html, css, django

I have this html in Django template:

```
<div id = "search_form">
        <form action="" method="get" id = "search-form">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            {{ form.media }}
        </form>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="search_submit" name = "search_submit" type="submit" value = "submit" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
</div>
```

How to make search bar and button inline? This is not working:

```
#search_submit {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: There is no input for searching in your HTML. Is it rendered by django? Can you show us the full rendered HTML?

Comment: Yes, it is rendered by {{form.as_p}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using bootstrap, try this (btw, the button should be inside the form tags):

```
<div id = "search_form">
  <form action="" method="get" id = "search-form">
   {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="col-xs-6">
     {{ form.as_p }}
     {{ form.media }}
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-6">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="search_submit" name = "search_submit" type="submit" value = "submit" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Than kinda worked in a way. Now everything is one line, but really far away from each other

Comment: Try playing around with the col values e.g. col-xs-9 and col-xs-3

Comment: Thanks. I had to to update your code a little bit, but you put me on the right path

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked:

```
<div id = "search_form">
    <div class="input-group">
        <form action="" method="get" id = "search-form">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <div class="col-xs-6">
                {{ form.as_p }}
                {{ form.media }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="search_submit" name = "search_submit" type="submit" value = "submit" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```